# Abort submission if validation fails php

Tags: php

I have been building a php form for some time and have passed through the various stages of validation. I have settled on validating with php. However; I can't figure out how to kill the script or abort submit if validation fails. I would have thought it would be as simple as `exit()`

Here's where I'm at;

```
// condition 
  $cont = '';
  $msg = '';

// define variables and set to empty values
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $titleErr = $emailErr = $dayErr = $monthErr = $timeErr = $chkErr = "";
$fnameField = $lnameField = $titleField = $emailField = $daySelect = $monthSelect = $timeSelect = $chk = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
    $timeErr = "Please select a time from the list";
    exit();
  } else {
    $timeSelect = test_input($_POST["time"]);
  }

}
  function test_input($data) {

  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

  return $data;
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-sub'])) {
  // code executed on submit 
  $headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
  $success = mail($emailAcc, $emailSub, $body, $headers); 

  if(!$success) {   
    $cont = "<b>Fatal Error:</b> Mail was not sent successfully.";
    exit(); 
  } else {
    $cont = "Success! Thank you! <br/> We'll see you there...";
    $msg = "Someone will be in touch with you shortly to confirm your details. Please check the supplied informaiton is correct below;";
  } 
} else {
   // code executed on first request
}
```

Any push I could get in the right direction would be of great help.

**NOTE:**
I have only included one of my validations as to keep the post a little more compact.

** Answered in chat **
My own stupidity caused this problem. (I was only setting the variables, if they weren't getting called, the script would never reach `exit();` thanks for the asssitance all.

Comment: You can use either exit(); or die(); and both will stop the execution of the script at the moment they are called. The only reason that the script will not stop executing should be that exit() is never reached from your code.

Comment: Why isn't it reaching `exit();` ? the variable `$timeErr` is being called just fine. Shouldn't `exit();` then be the next in line?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by the variable being called just fine. Your current code does not output the $timeErr anywhere so how would you know if it's called fine or not. Nevertheless try something simple. Add echo "test";exit(); at the top of your code, in this case your script should only output test and do nothing else.

Comment: `timErr;` is being called here, `<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { ?> 

              <div id="err">
                <?php echo $fnameErr, "<br/>", $lnameErr, "<br/>", $titleErr, "<br/>", $emailErr; ?> 
              </div> 

            <?php } ?>`

Comment: even the code you pasted does not have a relation to $timeErr variable, please try what i suggested above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109581/discussion-between-beaniie-and-jonid-bendo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried it with exit() or with die() and they both work correctly. This is my code snippet:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    //validate post variable != empty
    if (empty($_POST['name'])|| empty($_POST['lastname'])|| empty($_POST['email'])|| empty($_POST['phone']) ||empty($_POST['cellphone']) ||empty($_POST['dir'])) 
    {
    $response = json_encode(array("error" => "true","message" => "Error, please fill all the form data"));
    echo $response;
    exit();
}else{
    .
    .
    .
}

}
```